# Why the error " Cannot set properties of undefined..." appears in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, exception, angular-material

I am working on an application where a user can register, for this the user has to write data such as name, nickname, password, type of identification, etc ...

The model of user:

```
export class User{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    nickname: string;
    password: string;
    docType: {
        documentTypeId: number;
    }
}
```

The component .ts:

```
public insertUser(event: Event): void{
      event.preventDefault();
        
      const u: User = new User();

      u.id = this.form.value.id;
      u.name = this.form.value.name;
      u.nickname = this.form.value.nickname;
      u.password = this.form.value.password;
      u.docType.documentTypeId = Number(this.form.value.typeId); // the error occurs here

      /*send to API, save to DB... */ 
}
```

So, the error occurs when the value of `u.docType.documentTypeId` is assigned, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
u.docType = {
    documentTypeId: Number(this.form.value.typeId);
}
```

I believe it should!

Comment: Ok, it worked fine, but I don't understand why the assignment of the value has to be this way.

Comment: Basically in typescript, think of your docType as a new DocType() class. You have to declare it with a value before assigning it something.